# How to insert and update data for spring could config server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config

I have a lots of properties files for that I am using spring cloud config server. Now can anyone suggest me what is the best way to insert all my data.

One of the best solution is to do with rest apis and keep the value encrypted. So the concern is that is it ok to create rest endpoint in spring cloud config server.

Comment: did you thought of creating git repository of property files and fetching data from there, spring cloud config allows to keep your properties on github repo

Comment: @noob yes but that is not secure I feel as keep in git and keep in jar doesn't make much difference.